# Excel - Using one drop-down list to populate other drop-down lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, autocomplete, data-validation

I have a sheet consisting of about 10 drop down lists (among other fields). I want to create a master drop-down list, which would populate some of the other drop-down lists and/or other fields based on the value chosen in the master list. Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

In this example, Column A would be my master list. Columns B-D define dropdowns that would appear in other places on the sheet. If I select Steve from the master dropdown I would like the other dropdowns to all populate his preferences (for example Steve's House, Ground, and UPS). The same goes for the other people in the Shipping To field. Hopefully that is clear. If not please let me know what I need to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most effective way to do this without getting into VBA and to keep it simple is to point each drop down to a specific list like you normally would but to make that list that it is pointing to be dynamic.

For example I created the master drop down like so:
[image]

This is done like normal since the master does not change.

Now when I add my next drop down that will be dynamic, I make a column that depends on the first choice:

[image]

And then simply make another drop down that references the new list that was created.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much Eric!!!